# Checks whether a col [ of type datetime] is null or less than another literal datetime

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I have a very simple query:

The variable '_dc' is the Entity Framework Code First Data Context:

```
var maxLockTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1);
var record = _dc.DMPs
    .Where(x =>
        x.MappedId == null
        && x.Ignored == false
        && (x.ConcurrencyLockDate.Equals(null) || x.ConcurrencyLockDate < maxLockTime))
    .OrderBy(x => x.id).Skip(skip).Take(1).ToList()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.id,
        x.Ignored,
        x.MappedId,
        x.SourceData
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Produces the following SQL where clause:-

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[MappedId] IS NULL) 
AND (0 = [Extent1].[Ignored]) 
AND ([Extent1].[ConcurrencyLockDate] < @p__linq__1)
```

As you can see, the "null or equals" check on 'ConcurrencyLockDate' is incorrect as it does not include results where it is NULL.  I'm using EF5 RC with .NET 4.5 RC.

Does anyone know how I can do this?  It seems so simple so I am tearing my hair out.

Comment: A column of type `DateTime` cannot be null: `DateTime` is a non-nullable type. If it's nullable, it should be `DateTime?`. Do you still see the same behaviour if you change that? (Edit: in fact, I guess that's why you use `.Equals(null)`: did the compiler already tell you that comparing a `DateTime` to null using `== null` is pointless?)

Comment: oh sorry, I mean, I forgot to put '?' at the end of my DateTime! I am going to sack myself! thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, I've posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column of type `DateTime` cannot be null: `DateTime` is a non-nullable type. If it's nullable, the type should be `DateTime?`.